# Canvas Forced Update Not Working

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I'm providing swipe functionality to a widget in Kivy. I do not change its position or animate it, rather the swiping provokes the canvas of the widget to change color and alpha depending on the length and direction of the swipe. Creating this has not been an issue.
My problem lies in the *on_touch_up* event. I would like this event to bring the alpha to 100% and hold it there for half a second before clearing the canvas. After running some tests, it appears that the canvas update is constrained by the actual life cycle of the *on_touch_up* event; that is: the goddamned thing won't update until the event ends. I've tried the three different methods, all to no avail.

> The if/else sequence remains the same in the three examples of code, so I've excluded it from bullets 2 and 3:

- Forcing an update via *self.canvas.ask_update()*

  ```
  def on_touch_up(self, touch):
      if abs(self.x_total) > abs(self.y_total):
          if self.x_total < 0:
              self.canvas.add(Color(1, 0, 0, 1))
          else:
              self.canvas.add(Color(0, 1, 0, 1))
      else:
          if self.y_total < 0:
              self.canvas.add(Color(0, 0, 1, 1))
          else:
              self.canvas.add(Color(1, 1, 0, 1))

      self.canvas.add(Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size))
      self.canvas.ask_update()
      sleep(0.50)
      self.canvas.clear()
  ```
- Using a canvas *Callback* to perform the update outside the *on_touch_up* event

  ```
  def on_touch_up(self, touch):
      ...

      with self.canvas:
          Callback(self.update_final)
      sleep(0.50)
      self.canvas.clear()

  def update_final(self, instr):
      self.canvas.add(Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size))
  ```
- Creating a class-level Rectangle object and changing its values.

  ```
  def on_touch_up(self, touch):
      ...

      self.rect.pos = self.pos
      self.rect.size = self.size
      sleep(0.50)
      self.canvas.clear()
  ```

**Note:** If I remove the final self.canvas.clear(), what I witness is a half second pause after I release the touch, and then I get the 100% alpha I was looking for. Any ideas?